# How is it that $(2^k+1)3 \gt (2^k+1)2\gt 2^{k+1}+2\gt 2^{k+1}+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, induction

I am working on a mathematical induction worksheet, and my professor gave us the key. I have run across something that makes zero sense to me, so please explain if you can.

**Additional info:** $k \ge2$

Here is what she has:

What needs to be shown: $$ 3^{k+1} \gt 1 +2^{k+1} \tag0$$

$$3^{k+1} = 3^k(3) \gt (2^k+1)3 \tag1$$
This is where I am confused..
$$ \gt (2^k+1)2 \tag2$$
$$ \gt 2^{k+1}+2 \tag3$$
$$ \gt 2^{k+1}+1 \tag4$$

Comment: The second to last inequality ought to be an equality.  That is, $\left(2^k+1\right)\times 2=2^{k+1}+2$.

Comment: The part I am confused about it the jump from $(2^k+1)3$ to $(2^k+1)2$

Comment: The statement "$3^{k+1} > 1 + 2^{2k+1}$" is false for all positive integers $k$. Are you sure you have the statement copied down correctly?

Comment: should be $2^{k+1}$ I'll edit it

Comment: Clearly $\left(2^k+1\right)\times 3> \left(2^k+1\right)\times 2$.  More generally, $3x>2x$ if $x>0$.

Comment: So as long as the condition remains true, that coefficient can be changed to anything?

Answer (score 1):

> $\text{As is it was mentioned in the comments we have:}$
> $(2^k+1) \cdot 3 >(2^k+1) \cdot 2 \Rightarrow (2^k+1) \cdot 3>2^k \cdot 2+2 \Rightarrow  (2^k+1) \cdot 3>2^{k+1}\cdot 2>2^{k+1}+1$
> $\text{Finally:}$
> $(2^k+1) \cdot 3 >2^{k+1}+1.$
> $\text{A general formoula would be:}$
> $\ (2^k+1) \cdot 3 >(2^k+1) \cdot c \text{ with  c<3}$